# Foreground Notification not displaying

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using react-native-firebase to receive notifications, but in the previous version it had the Notification site, now it doesn't. Can anyone give me a help how could i implement?

Comment: How about writing specific information? As react-native-firebase versions, your code and so on.

Answer (score 0):

all the docs about react-native-firebase [is here](https://rnfirebase.io/)